# Is there a way to use OpenCV setMouseCallBack in a Kivy widget or window?

Tags: opencv, kivy, kivymd

I'm working in a project using Python and Kivy. There is a preexistent software, used for recognition of patterns in images with a fully working version, but that uses only command line. Now it is required a Graphic User Interface for it and the library chosen was Kivy.
The main difficulty I'm facing is that the software's core uses OpenCV and integrate it with Kivy is being very frustrating. Briefly, it works like this:
1 - An OpenCV window is presented in which user must select a Region of Interest (ROI).
2 - After the selection, another function (the main function) is called and begins the analysis within the region previously set.
3 - After the analysis is completed, results are presented in form of images and reports.

My problem is: I'm not being able to bring this openCV window to the Kivy interface. What I managed to accomplish so far is to mirror this OpenCV image inside the GUI, but the ROI selection still must be done from OpenCV window, so it is not what I need. Is there a way to "transform" an OpenCV window in a Kivy Window? If not, what would you suggest?

Thank you very much in advance

I already tried to:

- Mirror the OpenCV window into the Kivy GUI (works partially, as mouse inputs doesn't work)

Expectations:

- To have the input made in the image as values for being used inside the main function.

Comment: Forget about using HighGUI in the Kivy application, you will have to recreate all the functionality needed using Kivy. Prototype this stand-alone. You want to create a Kivy widget which can display a static image (say make a test PNG with a single filled rectangle), and which can handle [touch events](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/inputs.html). You may have to do some coordinate transformations to correctly map the event coordinates to image coordinates. | Seems like you already tried some of this, so show us a [mcve] and let's figure out why the mouse input is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to include my code as comment to your answer, but there was not enough space. Here is a reproductible example of the code I found and that answers partially my problem.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<ROIImage>
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: root.roi_color
        Rectangle:         
            pos: root.start_pos
            size: root.current_pos[0] - root.start_pos[0], \
              root.current_pos[1] - root.start_pos[1]

''')


class ROIImage(Image):
 start_pos = ListProperty([0, 0])
 current_pos = ListProperty([0, 0])
 roi_color = ListProperty([1, 1, 1, 0.5])

def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        touch.grab(self)
        self.current_pos = self.start_pos = touch.pos
        return True
    return False

def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if touch.grab_current is self:
        self.current_pos = touch.pos
        print(f'current pos: {touch.pos}')
        if (self.start_pos[0] < self.current_pos[0]) and (self.start_pos[1] 
< self.current_pos[1]):
            print("Top Right")
            self.roi_color = (100 / 255, 143 / 255, 165 / 255, 0.6)

        elif (self.start_pos[0] < self.current_pos[0]) and 
(self.start_pos[1] > self.current_pos[1]):
            print("Bottom Right")
            self.roi_color = (23 / 255, 143 / 255, 54 / 255, 0.6)

        elif (self.start_pos[0] > self.current_pos[0]) and 
(self.start_pos[1] < self.current_pos[1]):
            print("Top Left")
            self.roi_color = (100 / 255, 93 / 255, 65 / 255, 0.6)

        elif (self.start_pos[0] > self.current_pos[0]) and 
(self.start_pos[1] > self.current_pos[1]):
            print("Bottom Left")
            self.roi_color = (100 / 255, 45 / 255, 34 / 255, 0.6)
        return True
    return False

def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if touch.grab_current is self:
        self.current_pos = touch.pos
        print(f'End pos: {touch.pos}')
        return True
    return False

def clear(self):
    self.roi_color = (1, 1, 1, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kv_test = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ROIImage:
        id: roi_image
        source: 'image.jpg'
   Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(48)
        text: 'Clear'
        on_release: 
            roi_image.clear()
'''

class ROIIMAGEApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv_test)

ROIIMAGEApp().run()
```

I say partially, because it requires an image saved in local memory storage to work. I couldn't make it work having as input the camera itself (sorry, I'm new at Python and even newer to Kivy).

Anyhow, thank you very much so far!
Best regards